Husband says he hasn't watched videos that are on his watch history
My husbands watch history has several videos on it that he says he hasn't watched. Sometimes it will be even during times I know he wasn't on his phone. How does that happen and how do I know what videos he actually watched? Could someone have hacked his Facebook account even though its not showing hes logged in somewhere else?

I am reviewing deleted closed questions.  I was the one who closed this so I'm adding it to the reopen-review queue to allow the community a chance to do its own review and decide if it should remain closed or be reopened.
